# ContentProvider for files on removable micro-sd card for Android 11+

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-11, fileprovider

As FileProvider cannot serve from micro-sd card one has to make its own extending ContentProvider.

So i did time ago. And was working fine for all Android versions below 11.

It can serve files from the whole device including micro sd card.

So also from private getExternalFilesDirs()[0] and getExternalFilesDirs()[1].

Now see these two paths both on same micro-sd:

```
/storage/1234-5678/Documents/mytext.txt
/storage/1234-5678/Android/data/<package>/files/mytext.txt
```

They could be served.

But on an Android 11+ devices HTMLViewer and Chrome can only handle the first path.
The app itself can always handle its own files using path or own provider.

On Android 11+ own apps that were choosen with ACTON_VIEW and used .readLine() to read from uri could handle first path and failed for second path.
I could finally solve it for my own apps by not using .readLine() but looking at .available() and doing a direct .read() from inputstream.

This is the provider class i use:

```
public class ABCContentProvider extends ContentProvider {
String TAG = "abccontentprovider";

@Override
public ParcelFileDescriptor openFile(Uri uri, String mode) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    Log.d(TAG, "open-File() mode: " + mode );  // "r" | "w"
    Log.d(TAG, "open-File() uri.getEncodedPath(): " + uri.getEncodedPath() );

    String path = uri.getEncodedPath();

    File f = new File(path);

    if ( ! f.exists() )
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "path does not exist" );
        throw new FileNotFoundException(
                "in ABCProvider\n"
                        + path
                        + "\nmode: " + mode
        );
    }

    if ( mode.equals("r") )
        return (ParcelFileDescriptor.open(f,ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY));

    return (ParcelFileDescriptor.open(f,ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_WRITE));
}

// Omitted all other methods as they are not used.
// Android Studio will add them for you
}
```

In AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <provider
        android:name=".ABCContentProvider"
        android:authorities="aaa.bbb.ccc.provider"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" />
```

Use following uries for an ACTIEN_VIEW intent. (Change 1234-5678 accordingly to used micro sd card)

```
Uri uri1 = Uri.parse("content://aaa.bbb.ccc.provider/storage/1234-5678/Documents/mytext.txt");
Uri uri2 = Uri.parse("content://aaa.bbb.ccc.provider/storage/1234-5678/Android/data/<package>/files/mytext.txt");
```

Test the uries in the providing app first.

Following intent is used to start an external app.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
 intent.setDataAndType(uri, "text/plain");
 intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
 startActivity(intent);
```

My question is: Why, on Android 11 and 12, is ContentProvider for files on a micro sd card acting different for files from different locations?

I could solve the read problem for .txt files but if my external app wants to save edits it fails.

Update (Nov 5):

Following only with MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.
The idea came to mind that files deep in the directory tree would suffer from this behavior. So i copied

```
/storage/1234-5678/Android/data/<package>/files/mytext.txt
```

to

```
/storage/1234-5678/Endroid/data/<package>/files/mytext.txt
```

No problems with the latter for viewing and editing by external app.
The problem is only for files in app specific directory on micro sd card.

Comment: Android 11 made it so that all the files under /Android/Data can not be accessed. They can't be shared and only accessible for apps that access their own directories, that's why it behaves differently. In short, you can no longer share any files under /android/data/*.

Comment: @Dan Baruch, that is much to short as i can perfectly share all files from primary Android/data when files belong to my app. And sharing from removable Android/data goes in the same way. Only there is this quirck that i described. Please read again. `.. i can share any file the app can read itself ..`

Answer (score 0):

Apparenyly Google read my post.

But said nothing ;-)

The problem is solved.

At least on my device that just received the Android 12 update.