# Android 11- Read Android/data directory of specific app

Tags: android, file

I have built an app that access and retrieve files from another app that is placed in Android/data/.../files/Recordings. On older device it works but on android 11 version can't find them. Does anyone have any solution for this? The code below works on older versions but not in android 11.

```
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Android/data/.../files/Recordings";
    File directory = new File(path);
    File[] files = directory.listFiles();
    if (directory.canRead() && files != null) {
        showRecFiles(files);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Empty!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: Does this help? (Check the author's question it self) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69044359/contentprovider-for-files-on-removable-micro-sd-card-for-android-11#comment123535911_69044359

Comment: @Dan Baruch, i don't know why you quoted that post. It has nothing to do with it.

Comment: You can only reach ../Android/data using SAF.

Comment: Android 11 changed the behavior to prevent you from accessing that directory. The post of this question said he is able to read from /android/data directories, though it might help him.